# How to input declared variable in js into mssql query in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I have introduced some variables `a,b` and `c` as follows in my code

`var a = 10;
var b = 90;
var c = b - a + 1;`

```
req2.query('SELECT TOP(81) [Numbers], [Square_Root] FROM Kiso_task_table WHERE Numbers   >=  10  AND Numbers <= 90', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        else {
            console.log(data);
        }
        conn.close();
    });
```

I don't want to enter my data into query by "typing them from my finger". To be more precise, instead of `req2.query('SELECT TOP(81)` I want to have `req2.query('SELECT TOP(c)`, where variable `c` is already defined with assigned value.

Comment: `SELECT TOP(81)...` will give you up to 81 rows. I'm honestly not 100% sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to concatenate the variables (they don't seem to appear in your code anywhere)? Can you edit the post and add the expected results?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a parameterized query.

```
req2.query(`SELECT TOP(${c}) [Numbers], [Square_Root] FROM Kiso_task_table WHERE Numbers >=  ${a}  AND Numbers <= ${b}`, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        else {
            console.log(data);
        }
        conn.close();
    });
```

Comment: Having introduced those changes, console displays " RequestError: Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error
    at StreamEvents.req.once.err"

Comment: Undeleted...  I updated my answer with more code.  I'm assuming you're using the mssql npm package to query SQL Server.  Can you confirm that's the case?

Comment: Exactly, I'm using mssql npm package

Comment: Argh, sorry... I put single quotes in instead of backticks.  I've updated the answer.  Give it another try.

Comment: Ok.  Not sure what the issue is, it works on my side.

Comment: I don't know either, I've started programing since a few weeks. Anyway, I'll think about it - thank you for your SQL injection remark!

Answer (score 0):

```
req2.query('SELECT TOP('+ c +')[Numbers], [Square_Root] FROM Kiso_task_table WHERE Numbers >=' + a +  'AND Numbers <=' + b, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        else {
            console.log(data);
        }
        conn.close();
    });
```

Comment: While this works, don't do this.  You open yourself up to SQL injection attacks.